# Prime number generator is not working Python

Tags: python, numbers, generator

What I want to do is:

- create a "list" of odd numbers
- then test if they are prime
  the test will be done with multiples up to half of the value of the odd number hence halfodd
- put the prime number into a list
- print that list

however my result is a list of numbers from 1 to 1003 that skip 3, 4, and 5

Is there a semantic error here?

```
#Prime number generator 

def primenumber():
    primelist = [1, 2]
    num = 3
    even = num%2
    multi = 0
    result = 0
    while len(primelist) < 1000:
        if even != 0:
            oddnum = num
        i = 2
        halfodd = ((oddnum + 1)/2)
        while i < halfodd:
            i =+ 1
            multi = oddnum%i
            if multi == 0:
                result += 1
        if result != 0:
            primelist.append(oddnum)
            prime_num = oddnum
        num += 1
    print primelist

primenumber()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the source of the issue, but you never recalculate `even`, so it's not going to help you weed out even numbers that you test later in the code.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you uploaded. I can't even get output...If I change the number of primes to calculate down to as low a number as 5, the program doesn't terminate.

Comment: You could implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead, just a heads-up.

Comment: You also have `i =+ 1` where it should be `i += 1`. But you don't have that in the code you ran, otherwise you would have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if result != 0:
```

Since `result` is (supposed to be) a count of how many factors you found, you want

```
if result == 0:
```

You're also not resetting `result` when you advance to a new candidate prime, you never recompute `even`, and if you did, you'd be considering the odd numbers twice each.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def primenumber():
  primelist = [1, 2]
  candidate = 3
  while len(primelist) < 1000:
    isCandidatePrime = True
    if (candidate % 2 == 0): # if candidate is even, not a prime
      isCandidatePrime = False
    else:
      for i in range(3, (candidate+1)/2, 2): # else check odds up to 1/2 candidate
        if (candidate % i == 0): # if i divides it, not a prime
          isCandidatePrime = False
          break
    if (isCandidatePrime):
      primelist.append(candidate)
    candidate += 1
  print primelist
```

I think there are several improvements (check only numbers less than or equal to the square root of the candidate, only check prime numbers, not all numbers less than the square root of the candidate) but I'll leave that alone for now.